File corruption after file copying using python, how to fix it?
The following code is used:
Python
import os
import shutil

def backup_files(src_dir, dest_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
        for file in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            dest_file = os.path.join(dest_dir, file)
            shutil.copy2(src_file, dest_file)
src_dir0 = 'A:\\AI\\output'
src_dir1 = 'A:\\AI\\prompt'
dest_dir0 = 'D:\\AI 备份\\output'
dest_dir1 = 'D:\\AI 备份\\prompt'

if not os.path.exists(dest_dir0):
    os.makedirs(dest_dir0)

if not os.path.exists(dest_dir1):
    os.makedirs(dest_dir1)

backup_files(src_dir0, dest_dir0)
backup_files(src_dir1, dest_dir1)
print("备份完成！")

After running, the size of disk space occupied by the pictures in A:\AI\output remains unchanged, and you can still see some thumbnails of the pictures from the parent folder icon (I guess the Windows thumbnail cache has not been deleted), and then when you open it with "Photos", you will be prompted with the message "00002 a 2736957550.png doesn't seem to support this file format.". I'm not sure how to solve this problem, even if I restart my computer. How can I solve this problem?enter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here
I've tried restarting the computer and checking the code and there are no errors. Hopefully a professional will come and offer help, thanks a million.

disk space occupied by the pictures in A:\AI\output remains unchanged You're copying files from that directory to somewhere else, so yes of course those files are unchanged...

Please do not upload unnecessary images. I am not confident as to how these screenshots add to your post.

add some basic debugging ... print src_file dest_file before the call to  shutil.copy2(src_file, dest_file), as others mention - don't paste screenshots, if you need to to a simply copy/paste VERBATIM of what's on the console is almost always all that's needed.
